# rsync working as a script, but not as a cron job

Tags: rhel, cron, rsync

I have a basic script set up.

```
rsync -havP /this/source/ login@ip:/destination/path
```

Running this script manually works and syncs all the data properly. When I try to run say `00 18 * * * /script/location.sh` it will not run.

I have tried to do `00 18 * * * rsync -havP /this/source/ login@ip:/destination/path` without luck as well.

I am running RHEL 7.7, what am I missing to have either the script or command run from the crontab at whatever time I want. I have RSA ssh keys already set up and I am able to login from the source machine to dest machine without entering a password.

```
<no matches>
```

Comment: Which user is running the crontab? How do you pass the private key to `rsync`?

Comment: I'm under root when I use crontab -e. Root has its private key and the public key is already shared. I can successfully switch ssh sessions with entering a password

Comment: Is SELinux enabled and enforcing? (Please post output of `sestatus`.) If so, set SELinux to permissive mode, using `setenforce 0`. Check if the cronjob will run then. If it does, SELinux is the culprit, and you may then check the AVC audit logs using `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i` and post it here.

Comment: @Edward it was SElinux that was the issue. Is there an easy to add the exception with SElinux vs just changing the enforce to 0?

Comment: OK, could you please edit your post and add the output of the relevant part of the SELinux AVC audit log? (Run the cronjob and right after, run `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i`.) That way, we can all see what's causing the SELinux tripup.

Comment: Updated, It showed no matches

Comment: It might be that you need to supply the full path to rsync in the script.  what does the output of the cron command say?

Comment: The SSH key, does it not have a password? How is root supposed to enter that password when the cron job is running? Is there possibly an SSH agent running that the job could use (if `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set correctly)?